# SecurityException: Not allowed to start an Activity Intent

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

We are preparing to publish our instant app, however, we are experiencing an issue when running our AIA app in the AIA development track in Google Play.
Our AIA app runs perfectly from Android Studio, but this issue arises when attempting to run on a real device from the Play Store.
Any assistance is appreciated.

Error in question:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start activity Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=https://www.example.com/... pkg=com.example (has extras) }
```

Our AIA is set up to run `ACTION_VIEW` Intents as to open Activities listed in other features of the app, very much like the samples provided by Google.
When our app is opened via an URL, it is sent to a router Activity in our Base Feature to handle parsing the URI and open the proper Activity to handle the URL Path.

- Base Feature -- UrlRouterActivity
- Feature 1 -- Feature1Activity

Base Feature Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rentpath.lib">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.UrlRouterActivity"
            android:noHistory="true"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoDisplay">
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="http" />
                <data android:scheme="https" />
                <data android:host="www.example.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/path" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Feature 1 Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.rentpath.lib.pdp">

    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.Feature1Activity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data android:scheme="@string/filter_scheme_secure" /> <!-- String resource for https -->
                <data android:host="www.example.com" />
                <data android:pathPrefix="/action_feature_1" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="action_feature_1"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Our router Activity takes the URI, deconstructs the URL params and would construct an Intent as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https:www.example.com/action_feature_1?some_param=some_value"));
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

Starting this Activity results in the exception mentioned at the top.
Again, this only occurs when running the AIA app from the development track in Google Play.
It does not occur when running the AIA app from Android Studio.

Additional information:

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2
Gradle plugin: 3.0.0-beta2
Gradle wrapper distribution: 4.1-rc-1
```

Comment: No it is not a duplicate. Also, I've already added the solution. Did you even read the whole post?

Comment: Please answer the question below, not as an edit to the question

Comment: You don't need any rep to answer

Comment: Please check the public bug link for this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68084954, so you can track the updates here too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, that when running the AIA app from Google Play, string references do not play nicely with the manifests. Explicitly setting the string value on the scheme fixes the issue.

Replacing

```
<data android:scheme="@string/filter_scheme_secure" />
```

with

```
<data android:scheme="https" />
```

resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, `data` attributes cannot be resources, only strings

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html

Compared to service tags, which do list some attributes that can be string resources. (the labels)

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Main reason I can think of is that labels can be different languages and are changed at runtime. You don't have very many options for URI schemes and they're not changing during the app lifetime